# ZipArchive not saving file on live server in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, server, zip

I have some encrypted responses that I convert to a Zip file in my Laravel application. The function below downloads the API response, saves it as a Zip file, and then extracts it while I read the folder's contents. In my local environment, it works well. However, the Zip file is not getting saved to the storage folder on the live server. No error is being shown, only an empty JSON response. Please, what could be the cause?

```
public function downloadZipAndExtract($publication_id, $client_id)
{
    /* We need to make the API call first */
    $url = $this->lp_store."clients/$client_id/publications/$publication_id/file";
    $file = makeSecureAPICall($url, 'raw');

    // Get file path. If file already exist, just return
    $path = public_path('storage/'.$publication_id);
    if (!File::isDirectory($path)) {
        Storage::put($publication_id.'.zip', $file);

        // Zip the content
        $localArchivePath = storage_path('app/'.$publication_id.'.zip');
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        if (!$zip->open($localArchivePath)) {
            abort(500, 'Problems experienced while reading file.');
        }

        // make directory with the publication_id 
        // then extract everything to the directory
        Storage::makeDirectory($publication_id);
        $zip->extractTo(storage_path('app/public/'.$publication_id));

        // Delete the zip file after extracting
        Storage::delete($publication_id.'.zip');
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd check is if the storage file is created and if it isn't created, create it. Then I'd look at your file permissions and make sure that the the groups and users permissions are correct and that you aren't persisting file permissions on creation. I've had many instances where the process that's creating files(or trying) is not in the proper group and there is a sticky permission on the file structure.